# Xively & CurrentCost

Tags: xively

Not sure if this is possible anymore or not. But I have been playing around with Xively and trying to make the connection from my CurrentCost Energy monitor to the Xively servers/interface.

Does Xively still support this feature or do I need to find another service? The documentation is very well laid out but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to connect my device to the service.

Has anyone done this?

Jeremy